# Ошибка с присваиванием координат картинке на движке Corona

Tags: изображения, lua, coronasdk, координаты

```
data = {
  img_x = 300,
  img_y = 200,
  stt_x = 700,
  stt_y = 200,
  dex_x = 500,
  dex_y = 550
}
local pkmn_image = display.newImageRect(pok_x.image, 300, 300)
pkmn_image.x = data.img_x
pkmn_image.y = data.img_y
```

Столкнулся с проблемой присваивания координат картинке. На предпоследней строке выдает ошибку:

> attempt to index local 'pkmn_image' (a nil value)

Примечание: я брал пример кода с официальной документации Corona, и раньше оно работало (очень странно).

Comment: У вас точно в оригинальном коде нету опечатки? `print(pkmn_image)` что выводит?

Comment: Заменил неизвестное **pok_x.image** на свой файл **'corona.png'**, проверил - ошибок нет, картинка видна. Так что в этом фрагменте копать нечего. Присваивание идёт как надо.